# List of Variables in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, entity

Is there a way to create a `std::vector` like list, but which only contains **1** value, without a key.

What I basically want to do is store a whole bunch of Entities. Also it'd be nice if I could remove objects by key. (e.g. `map::remove(Entity*);`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. It is called `std::set`. It is a set of values of a certain type.

For example:

- `std::set<int>` will store `int`s.
- `std::set<Entity>` will store `Entity` objects (instances of the type `Entity`).
- `std::set<Entity *>` will store pointers to Entity.

Comment: Will an std::set allow polymorphism?

Comment: Oh, I guess I could just store the Entity, and a separate property that is a part of the Entity which contains what it can / should be casted to?

Comment: @Binero An interesting question (the first one). Let Stack Overflow answer it: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3687808/96780

Comment: @Binero About your second question, I will just tell you what *I* have done. I have used std::set with basic types, no polymorphism (integer, double, string, etc.). And I have used std::set with _pointers_, i.e. std::set<Entity *>. And I have sometimes used std::set<Entity>, but this does not exhibit polymorphic behaviour. I have never needed more than that, actually.

Comment: Just a quick note that to store items in an `std::set`, you need to define comparison for that type, so you need to either overload `operator<` for your `Entity` class, or else specify a comparison function/functor when creating the `set`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean `std::map`, not `std::vector`?

In that case you could use a `std::set` or `std::unordered_set`

Comment: The whole point of a map is the key, so an std::vector is closer to what I want than an std::map...

Comment: @Binero Among the "keyless" containers, a std::vector and a std::list allow repetitions. A std::set does not allow repetitions (that's what it's designed for).