# Polymorphism and Dynamic Casting

Tags: c++, polymorphism, game-engine, software-design, game-development

So I'm working on a text-based RPG, and I've run into an issue. I am currently working on equipping weapons from the character's inventory. I am trying to make it so that my program can tell if the item they want to equip is of class `Weapon` or not. Here is the clip of relevant code:

```
 Item tempChosenWeapon = myInventory.chooseItem();
cout << tempChosenWeapon.getName() << endl;
Item *chosenWeapon = &tempChosenWeapon;
cout << chosenWeapon->getName() << endl;//THE CODE WORKS UP TO HERE

Weapon *maybeWeapon = dynamic_cast<Weapon*>(chosenWeapon);
cout << maybeWeapon->getName() << endl;
```

Now, `Weapon` is a child class of `Item`, which is why I am using dynamic cast -- in an attempt to change `chosenWeapon`, which is of type `Item`, to type `Weapon` in order to compare the two classes. (I am using these `cout<<`s in or to test whether or not calling a function from these objects works).

My program compiles, and everything runs fine until we come to `maybeWeapon->getName()`, in which the program crashes. I've researched quite a bit, but I just don't understand what I am doing wrong. Any answer or alternative suggestion is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: what do you think dynamic_cast does if its not a Weapon?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast

Comment: casting is normally a design flaw.  You could solve this by using an enum that has the different classes of items you can have then then have a `virtual getItemType()` function that returns the type.  This way you don't have to cast and deal with all of the pitfalls.

Comment: I think you don't need to know the exact class. I think that all you want to know is whether the item can be equipped. So, one alternative approach is to have all objects inherit an `Equip()` method from `Item`. Defining this as a virtual function allows `Weapon` objects to respond in one way, and (say) `Talisman` objects to do something else, while the base class `Equip()` does nothing (or prints a hint/error for the user).

Comment: Cast fails, you get a `nullptr`, you dereference the return value without checking, bad things ensue.

Comment: Consider adding a polymorphic method "is_weapon()", that returns bool.  Derived classes implement their own answer uniquely, and  in a single line of code. To reduce effort, all the non-weapons could use the base-class defined "is_weapon()" which returns false.  Perhaps your weapon's have grades (tank, etc.)  is_weapon() could return the grade enum.  non-weapons would be valid, but clearly not a weapon.  So many way to avoid dynamic-casting.  I agree with Nathan, casting is a design flaw.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The problem

The problem is that you try to make a dynamic cast to a `Weapon` but in reality the object pointed to is a true copy constructed `Item` and not a subclass.  This is results in a `nullptr` and UB when you dereference it !

### Why ?

Let's suppose that you have only `Weapon` objects in your inventory.  The first instruction in your snippet is the root of your evil:

```
    Item tempChosenWeapon = myInventory.chooseItem();
```

This is statement **is a copy construction of an `Item` object**. If the source object was a `Weapon`, it will be **[sliced](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/object-slicing-in-c/)**.

Later you take a pointer to this object:

```
    Item *chosenWeapon = &tempChosenWeapon;
```

But this `Item*` doesn't point to a `Weapon` object as you think.  It points to a real crude `Item` object ! So when you do the dynamic cast here:

```
    Weapon *maybeWeapon = dynamic_cast<Weapon*>(chosenWeapon);
```

the code will find out that `choosenWeapon` is not a `Weapon*`, and the result of `dynamic_cast` will be a `nullptr`. Until now it's not necessarily a catastrophe.  But when you then derefence this pointer you get UB:

```
    maybeWeapon->getName()     // OUCH !!!!!!
```

### Solution

Checking if the `dynamic_cast` was successful (i.e. result not `nullptr`) is a protection against the crash, but will not solve your root problem.

It is even possible that the problem is even deeper than expected: what type does the `myInventory.chooseItem()` return in reality ?  Is it a plain Item ?  Then you might have the slicing problem already in the inventory !

If you want to use polymorphism:

- you have to work with pointers (preferably smart pointers) or with references, in order not to loose the original type of an object, like it happened here.
- If you need to copy polymorphic objects, you can't just use an assignment with an `Item`: you'd need to invoke a polymorphic `clone()` function and ensure that the target of this cloning has a compatible type.

To start with a solution, it's something like this:

```
Item* chosenWeapon = myInventory.chooseItem();  // refactor choosItem() to return a pointer.
cout << chosenWeapon->getName() << endl; 
Weapon *maybeWeapon = dynamic_cast<Weapon*>(chosenWeapon);
if (maybeWeapon) 
    cout << maybeWeapon->getName() << endl;
else cout << "Oops the chosen item was not a weapon" <<endl;
```

If this still not work, then your inventory container would be flawed.   In this case, look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41045/3723423) before opening a separate question with the code of your container

Comment: The slice is indeed the root of the problem, which other answer miss.

Comment: Thank you very much! One thing I don't understand here, however: why do you have the if statement as if (maybeWeapon); it doesn't seem like it should be a true/false statement here... would you mind elaborating? Thanks!

Comment: @TheMachoMuchacho the if statement takes for true every expression that is not null. So if(maybeWeapon) will have exactly the same behavior than if(maybeWeapon!=nullptr).

Comment: Ah, I see! Well thank you so much for your time and your help!

Answer (score 3):

dynamic_cast will return nullptr if the pointer cast cannot be performed (for reference casts it will throw an exception), so your code should read something like:

```
Weapon *maybeWeapon = dynamic_cast<Weapon*>(chosenWeapon);
if ( maybeWeapon  ) {
   cout << maybeWeapon->getName() << endl;
else {
   // it's not a weapon
}
```

If you don't perform that test, and try to dereference the pointer containing nullptr, you are off in Undefined Behaviour Land.

Answer (score 0):

```
Item tempChosenWeapon = myInventory.chooseItem();
```

this is an `Item`.  Not a type descended from `Item`.  It is an `Item`.

Values in C++ have known types.

```
cout << tempChosenWeapon.getName() << endl;
```

all good, but please stop `using namespace std;`

```
Item *chosenWeapon = &tempChosenWeapon;
```

This is a pointer to an `Item`.  I can prove it is not polymorphic, because it is a pointer to a instance of type `Item`.  The compiler can probably prove it to.

```
cout << chosenWeapon->getName() << endl;//THE CODE WORKS UP TO HERE
```

ok, this repeats the previous call.

```
Weapon *maybeWeapon = dynamic_cast<Weapon*>(chosenWeapon);
```

This deterministically returns `nullptr`.  `chosenWeapon` is an `Item*` that we know points to an `Item`, and an `Item` is not a `Weapon`.

```
cout << maybeWeapon->getName() << endl;
```

this dereferences `nullptr`.

---

There are a number of ways to handle polymorphism in C++.  But you have to think about it.

First, do you want value semantics?  Value sematnics means that a copy of something is a copy of it.  Things don't refer to other things; they are those things.

You can do value semantics with polymorphic values, but it takes a bit of work.  You write two classes; the value wrapper, and the internal `pImpl`.

The internal `pImpl` has a `std::unique_ptr<Impl> Impl->clone() const` method, and the value wrapper calls it when you copy it.

You write your interface like this:

```
template<class D>
struct clonable {
  std::unique_ptr<D> clone() const = 0;
};
struct ITarget;
struct IItem:clonable<IItem> {
  virtual std::string get_name() const = 0;
  virtual bool can_equip( ITarget const& ) const = 0;
  ~virtual IItem() {}
};
struct Target;
struct Item {
  using Impl = IItem;
  explicit operator bool() const { return (bool)pImpl; }
  IItem* get_impl() { return pImpl.get(); }
  IItem const* get_impl() const { return pImpl.get(); }
  template<class D>
  D copy_and_downcast() const& {
    auto* ptr = dynamic_cast<typename D::Impl const*>( pImpl.get() );
    if (!ptr) return {};
    return D(ptr->clone());
  }
  template<class D>
  D copy_and_downcast() && {
    auto* ptr = dynamic_cast<typename D::Impl*>( pImpl.get() );
    if (!ptr) return {};
    pImpl.release();
    return D(std::unique_ptr<typename D::Impl>(ptr));
  }
  std::string get_name() const {
    if (!*this) return {};
    return pImpl->get_name();
  }
  bool can_equip(Target const& target)const{
    if (!*this) return false;
    if (!target) return false;
    return pImpl->can_equip( *target.get_impl() );
  }
  Item() = default;
  Item(Item&&) = default;
  Item& operator=(Item&&) = default;
  Item(std::unique_ptr<IItem> o):pImpl(std::move(o)) {}
  Item(Item const& o):
    Item( o?Item(o.pImpl->clone()):Item{} )
  {}
  Item& operator=( Item const& o ) {
    Item tmp(o);
    std::swap(pImpl, tmp.pImpl);
    return *this;
  }
private:
  std::unique_ptr<IItem> pImpl;
};
```

which probably has bugs and is maybe too complex for you.

---

Second, you can go with reference semantics.

In this case, you want to return `shared_ptr<const T>` or `shared_ptr<T>` from your data.  Or you can go half way and return a `unique_ptr<T>` copy from your `chooseItem` functions.

Reference semantics is really hard to get right.  But you do get to use `dynamic_cast` or `dynamic_pointer_cast` directly.

```
std::shared_ptr<Item> chosenWeapon = myInventory.chooseItem();
if (!chosenWeapon) return;
std::cout << chosenWeapon->getName() << std::endl;

auto maybeWeapon = dynamic_pointer_cast<Weapon>(chosenWeapon);
if (maybeWeapon)
  std::cout << maybeWeapon->getName() << std::endl;
else
  std::cout << "Not a weapon" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast an object of type `Item` to an object of a subclass of `Item`.
Note that with `Item tempChosenWeapon = myInventory.chooseItem()`, you will get an Item-object, even if `chooseItem` might return a `Weapon`-object. This is called "slicing" and cuts out an `Item`-subobject of any `Weapon`-object. Note that variables that are not references or pointers are not polymorphic:

```
struct A {
    int a = 0;
    virtual void print() const {
        std::cout << "a:" << a << std::endl;
    }
};

struct B : public A {
    int b = 1;
    void print() const override {
        std::cout << "a:" << a << "; b:" << b << std::endl;
    }
};

B b;

A get_b() {  // will slice b;
    return b;
}

A& getRefTo_b() {  // reference to b; polymorphic
    return b;
}

A* getPointerTo_b() {  // pointer to b; polymorphic.
    return &b;
}

int main() {

    A a1 = get_b(); // copy of A-subobject of b; not polymorphic
    a1.print();
    // a:0

    A a2 = getRefTo_b();  // copy of A-subobject of referenced b-object; not polymorphic
    a2.print();
    // a:0

    A &a3 = getRefTo_b(); // storing reference to b-object; polymorphic
    a3.print();
    // a:0; b:1

    A *a4 = getPointerTo_b();  // pointer to b-object; polymorphic
    a4->print();
    // a:0; b:1

    B* b1 = dynamic_cast<B*>(&a1);  // fails (nullptr); a1 is not a B
    B* b2 = dynamic_cast<B*>(&a2);  // fails (nullptr); a2 is not a B
    B* b3 = dynamic_cast<B*>(&a3);  // OK; a3 refers to a B-object
    B* b4 = dynamic_cast<B*>(a4);   // OK; a4 points to a B-object

    return 0;
}
```

So your signature should probably be

```
Item &Inventory::chooseItem() {
   static Weapon weapon;
   ...
   return weapon;
};

int main() {
   Item &myWeapon = myInventory.chooseItem();
   Weapon* w = dynamic_cast<Weapon*>(&myWeapon);
   ...
}
```